# Can Eclipse be used to generate the Scala inferred object type?

Tags: eclipse, scala, intellij-idea, type-inference

With Intellij it is possible to generate the type of a variable. For example :

```
val rec = "String"
```

can be converted to

```
val rec : String = "String"
```

using the Intellij IDE.

Can Eclipse be used in same way : generate the type of variable within the source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scala IDE 4 nightly contains this feature as a quick fix (not sure if the RC does too).

Just hit CTRL+1 when your cursor is placed on the given expression.

[image: explicit_type]

Answer (score 0):

Hovering over the variable also displays the type of the variable which can be copied/pasted but not as clean as accepted answer.